# Filtrar resultados usando 3 tabelas no Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Criar no `controller` um filtro que pegue dados de 3 tabelas diferentes. Abaixo coloquei o relacionamento e um exemplo do que precisa acontecer. Não estou sabendo criar no `controller` o filtro que deve pegar como referência 02 parâmetros que vão ser passados na URL de acordo com a escolha do usuário. O que está funcionando: Quando eu cadastro um **Curso**, eu coloco a **Area de Atuação** e a **Categoria**, isso esta funcionando e salvando direitinho no DB.

Agora o que eu preciso fazer é: No site, tenho um menu que pega as Categorias e um submenu que lista as Áreas. Tipo: Paro o mouse em Pós Graduação e lista todas as áreas que possui. Eu quero filtrar na view de cursos apenas os que são de Pós Graduação e da Área que ele clicou.

A URL ficaria assim no caso, exemplo

```
http://localhost/SiteNovo/public/pos-graduacao/saude
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os relacionamentos estão assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E meu `controller` estão assim por enquanto:

```
public function cursos($categoria, $area){

    $cursos = Curso::all();
    $categorias = CategoriaCurso::all();
    $areas = AtuacaoArea::all();

    //Filtrar cursos

    return view('site.cursos.cursos',compact('cursos'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No método `cursos` da classe `SiteController` deve possuir a seguinte assinatura:

```php
class SiteController extends Controller 
{
     public function cursos($id_categoria_curso, $id_atuacao_area)
     {

     }
}
```

isso vai resolver a sua recuperação, mas, tenha cuidado com os valores retornados e critique-os para ver se os dados realmente é do tipo esperado (***validar dados***).

---

Se por acaso esses dois parâmetros forem do tipo número [pode usar a parte de restrição na rota (*Regular Expression Constraints*)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints), então na sua configuração de rota faça:

```php
Route::get('/cursos/{id_categoria_curso}/{id_atuacao_area}', 'SiteController@cursos')
     ->name('cursos')
     ->where(['id_categoria_curso' => '[0-9]+', 'id_atuacao_area' => '[0-9]+']);
```

---

Outros exemplos de restrição de rota:

***Restrição de texto:***

```php
Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) {
    //
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

***Restrição de números:***

```php
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

***Conjunto de restrição:***

```php
Route::get('user/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {
    //
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+']);
```

<sup>Referencia:[Laravel - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)</sup>

Para filtrar o cursos com `Eloquent`:

```php
class SiteController extends Controller 
{
     public function cursos($id_categoria_curso, $id_atuacao_area)
     {
          $cursos = Curso::where('id_categoria_curso', $id_categoria_curso)
              ->where('id_atuacao_area', $id_atuacao_area)
              ->get();
     }
}
```

Na documentação do `Eloquent` [Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries) tem as diversas formas de filtrar campos de um tabela, ordernar e assim por diante.

Comment: Certo, fiz os ajustes na Rota. Por enquanto estou pegando com id's mesmo, mas depois vou passar os nomes para a url ficar mais clara pro usuário. Mas eu ainda não entendi como ficaria o SQL no Método cursos da classe SiteController. Pode me auxiliar?

Comment: Olha @JunioAraujo se você postar o seus 3 modelos (`Entity`) é até respondo, mas, claro que isso não tem na sua pergunta inicial e fica claro que falta sempre dizer quais relacionamentos as mesmas tem!

Comment: Precisa colocar os `Models` se assim estiver usando e também as classe, se não do MER da relação ! e o resultado esperado @JunioAraujo

Comment: alterei a pergunta e coloquei exemplos e prints do que preciso. Veja se consegue me ajudar assim. Estou perdido nisso

Comment: você conseguiu entender minha dúvida? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @JunioAraujo já fiz a edição e está lá! basicamente é aquilo ... precisa dar uma olhada no Laravel Eloquent documentação.

Comment: deu certo assim! Muito obrigado pela força amigão. Só aproveitando uma coisa: Se eu quiser mostrar os nomes agora pra não ficar os id's na url, muda muita coisa? Tenho que mudar a rota e no Eloquent muda muito?